# How to export a "sliced face" of an object into a dxf?

Tags: mesh, export, edit-mode, faces, knife-tool

I know my question sounds weird but I will try to be specific as possible. Please be patient and please don't flag this question with another question: I would like to hear what everyone needs to say even if its a negative feedback, this is a serious project.

I am testing a feature called Variable Data Cutting (VDC) on the UI of a non-visible class 5 laser die-cutting machine designed to mass produce intricate folding cartons. ↓

[image]

*Fun fact: Conventional die-cut manufacturing techniques cannot achieve this level of intricate cutting. This being said, this technology allows us to innovative widely.*

As for Blender, this process is critical. Indeed Blender is a powerful tool and can be utilized in high-end production processes.

I use flat planes as a splitting tool to split an obj or stl object(s). After splitting the object, **I would like to know how to export the *"sliced face"* as a dxf.** The UI only reads dxf, dwg and even PDF. Below is an example of what I am depicting. ↓

[image]

*Actual thickness would be .20 mm*

[image]

**I would like to know how to export the *"sliced face"* as a dxf.**

Thank you for taking **YOUR** time to help me out, and if there is something anyone needs more explanation on please let me know so I can quickly revise anything.

Comment: Since Blender is a geometry based mesh modeling software, and what you seem to need is more in the realm of CAD (curve based) modeling, I would recommend exporting the mesh to a CAD program and then convert to .dxf from there. I would suggest exporting your model from blender as .fbx, and then download the free trial or hobby version of **Fusion360** and use it to convert the .fbx to .dxf.

Comment: There is a .dxf exporter but you have to enable it in the preferences. It will export as meshes though and not vector based entities